# How can i change the value of highchart in ng-repeat with click button in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have a table that have an  information and if click the line it open a charts and i want when i click button change the value of charts of the line i opened and not the other chart in the table

I used highchart and angularjs directive

```
<tr ng-if="item.expanded" ng-repeat-end="">
    <td colspan="100%">
            <table class="table" style="table-layout: fixed;">
                    <tr>
                            <td>
                                    <select class="combobox input-large form-control" name="normal" ng-model="sdate">
                                            <option ng-repeat="x in date" value="{{x.id}}">{{x.id}}</option>
                                    </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                    <button ng-click="sendPost(sdate,item.id)" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td>
                                    <hc-chart id="chart" options="chartOptions">CPU </hc-chart>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                    <hc-chart1 id="chart1" options="chartOptions1">Memoire </hc-chart>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td>
                                    <hc-chart2 id="chart2" options="chartOptions2">Réseau </hc-chart>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                    <hc-chart3 id="chart3" options="chartOptions3">Stockage </hc-chart>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td>
                                    <hc-pie-chart ng-if="ready" title="Browser usage" item="item">Placeholder for pie chart</hc-pie-chart>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
    </td>
```

please help me

Comment: You have to reinitialize the chart when the button clicks with the parameter of id and the row data.

Comment: or load the charts in row by default and hide the row when the row button clicks show the chart result for that row